# Is there a way to update a pair in a vector of pairs in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector, unordered-map, std-pair

This function tries to find a way for plan a journey given two vectors A and B, A[i] being the source of a trip and B[i] being the destination of a trip.
Here is the code but it seeming to get on an infinite loop since the value in pair doesn't get updated.

```
vector<string> solve(vector<string> A, vector<string> B) {
    
    unordered_map<string, vector<pair<string, char>>> map;
    auto f = map.find(A[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        
        f = map.find(A[i]);
        
        if(f == map.end())
            map[A[i]] = {make_pair(B[i], 'r')};
            
        else
            (f->second).push_back(make_pair(B[i], 'r'));
        
    }
    auto cmpfn = [](pair<string, char> x, pair <string, char> y){return x.first < y.first;};
    for(auto f = map.begin(); f != map.end(); f++){
        sort((f->second).begin(), (f->second).end(), cmpfn);
        
    }
    
    vector<string> res;
    
    auto start = map[A[0]];
    string dst;
    int i;
    res.push_back(A[0]);
    while(true){
        
        for(i = 0; i < start.size(); i++){
            cout << start[i].first << " " << start[i].second << endl;
            if(start[i].second == 'r'){
                dst = start[i].first;
                start.at(i).second = 'b';  // can't be updated
                break;
            }

        }
        

        if(i == start.size())
            break;
        
        res.push_back(dst);
        start = map[dst];

        
    }
    cout << endl;
    return res;
}
```

Can someone help me find why value in that pair couldn't be updated and suggest a better approach?

Edit: I could solve the problem by changing `auto start = map[A[0]];` to `vector<pair<string, char>> &start = map[A[0]];` since I was updating just a copy of the `vector` in the previous method.

Comment: The `map` stores ***copies*** of the vectors. You also copy again when assigning to `start`. And of course the arguments vectors `A` and `B` are copied, as well when you return `res`. Are all this copying intended (or needed)?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program step by step, one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables after each line executes, what did you see?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no I wanted to update the value of pair.second to mark it as visited, so that I don't revisit it... well so is there some better approach?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I value of pair.second stayed the same, and that's the reason there was an infinte loop, (pair.second was used to mark a node visited) and I wanted a way to edit it...

Comment: I recommend adding a [mre], complete with input and expected output set to the question. That way we can run the sucker for ourselves and see what happens. However, the true beauty of making a MRE is you usually find and fix the problem yourself while making it. Everybody wins.

Comment: How do you detect that `start[i].second` doesn't get modified? And remember that each iteration of the outer `while (true)` loop you *change* `start`. And since you copy the vectors, you loose all changes you made to the previous `start` when you do the assignment `start = map[dst]`

Comment: Now, you just need to figure out why it "stayed the same", again this  is something that a debugger helps to determine. Your debugger has various tools like showing the actual memory address of each variable, setting up watchpoints, etc... Good luck!

Comment: In `f = map.find(A[i]); if(f == map.end()) map[A[i]] = {make_pair(B[i], 'r')}; else (f->second).push_back(make_pair(B[i], 'r'));` , the `find()` is redundant. `map::operator[]` will create a new `vector` if the requested `string` is not found, otherwise it will return an existing `vector`, so take advantage of that: `map[A[i]].push_back(make_pair(B[i], 'r'));` is all you need.

Comment: @AdeebHS You can do `auto &start = map[A[0]];` to declare a reference to vector of sting+char pairs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is making a lot of *copies* of all of the objects involved, so it makes sense that trying to make modifications of those objects is not having the effect you want.  You need to make use of references/pointers to avoid those copies.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
vector<string> solve(const vector<string> &A, const vector<string> &B) {

    if (B.size() < A.size()) throw invalid_argument("B has fewer elements than A");

    unordered_map<string, vector<pair<string, char>>> map;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        map[A[i]].push_back(make_pair(B[i], 'r'));
    }

    auto cmpfn = [](const pair<string, char> &x, const pair<string, char> &y){ return x.first < y.first; };
    for(auto &elem : map) {
        sort(elem.second.begin(), elem.second.end(), cmpfn);
    }

    vector<string> res;
    string dst = A[0];

    do {
        auto &start = map[dst];
        res.push_back(dst);

        size_t i;
        for(i = 0; i < start.size(); ++i) {
            auto &p = start[i];
            cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
            if (p.second == 'r') {
                dst = p.first;
                p.second = 'b';
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == start.size()) break;
    }
    while (true);

    cout << endl;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: There are more copies in the lambda.  Elements are std::pair<const string, char>, but it takes a _non-const_ string, so makes a full copy of the pair passed in, and the reference is bound to that temporary.  Better is (for OP) to not create or pass in the lambda in the first place, since `sort` will already use `std::less<>`, which works on `std::pair` out of the box, if elements are comparable.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis You might be thinking of the `pair` that is used for the `unordered_map::value_type`, but that is not the `pair` being passed to the lambda. The `unordered_map::mapped_type` is being passed to the lamdba, and that `pair` does not use `const` strings. There should be no copies made in this code, except for the `push_back`s. Also, a `pair`'s `operator<` will compare both fields, but the OP's lambda is comparing only the first field.